# Angular 4 call 2 component

Tags: angular

I have two compoments:

UserComponent:

```
export class UserComponent {

@ViewChild(ProfileComponent)
profileComponent:ProfileComponent;

constructor(private userService: UserService, private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,private messageService: MessageService) {}
}
```

ProfileComponent:

```
export class ProfileComponent {

@ViewChild(ProfileComponent)
userComponent: UserComponent;

constructor(private profileService: ProfileService, private confirmationService: ConfirmationService,private messageService: MessageService) {}
}
```

I want using ProfileComponent in UserComponent and using UserComponent in ProfileComponent, but it's not working.

Comment: You can't / shouldn't. You would have an circular dependency and infinit loop in this case.

Comment: Circular dependency detected: is showing but i don't know using it. Can you help me? #Igor

Comment: Get a Service allowing them to communicate and share data via, Or make one of them parent, and the other Child, Or get a Parent component, so that they become siblings.

Comment: Think about it... You creates a UserComponent somewhere with a Profile component in it's template. The system will then create the Profile component but it requires a UserComponent so it creates one, but this has a Profile component so it creates one, and it has a User component so it creates one, and on and on and on. That is a circular dependency.

Comment: #Igor. I understand, It is a circular dependency. So how to call UserComponent on ProfileComponent and opposite in this issue

Comment: You don't because they are both not children of each other. Instead place them side by side on some other component and have it facilitate any communication between the 2 or communicate using a common service.

Comment: #Igor Thank a lot !.

Comment: On an unrelated note. In comments on [so] use the `@` symbol to prefix someone's username when you want to get their attention. Example: @LYNK. The `#` symbol does not do anything.